# dockerfile for backend and a seperate one for dbms because compose wont let me copy sql file into dbms container?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a dockerfile for frontend, one for backend, and one for the database.
In the backend portion of the project, I have a dockerfile and a docker-compose.yml file.
the dockerfile is great for the backend because it configures the backend, copies and sets up the information etc.  I like it alot.

The issue i have come to though is that if i can easily create a dockerfile for the dbms, but it requires me to put it in a different directory, where i was hoping to just define it in the same directory as the backend, and because of the fact the backend and the dbms is so tightly coupled, i figured this is where docker-compose would go.

My issue I ran into is that in a compose file, I cant do a COPY into the dbms container.  I would just have to create another dockerfile to set that up.  I was thinking that would work.

When looking on github, there was a big enhancement thread about it, but the closest people would get is just creating  volume relationship, which fails to do what I want.

Ideally, All i want to be able to do is to stand up a postgres dbms in a fashion such that i could conduct load balancing on it later down the line with 1 write, 5 read or something, and have its initial db defined in my one sql file.

Am I missing something?  I thought i was going about it correctly, but maybe I need to create a whole new directory with a dockerfile for the dbms.

Thoughts on how I should accomplish this?

Right now i was doing something like:

```
version: '2.0'
services:
    backend:
        build: .
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
    database:
        image: "postgres:10"
        environment: 
            POSTGRES_USER: "test"
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "password"
            POSTGRES_DB: "foo"
        # I shouldnt have volumes as it would copy the entire folder and its contents to db.
        volumes:  
            - ./:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Comment: What do you need to copy into the database container?  If your application uses any sort of migration framework, you should be able to do the minimal environment-variable setup you show and then run migrations; if you need the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` mechanism, you can bind-mount files there.  You shouldn't need a Dockerfile for it.

Answer (score 0):

To copy things with docker there an infinite set of possibilities.

**At image build time:**

- use COPY or ADD instructions
- use shell commands including cp,ssh,wget and many others.

**From the docker command line:**

- use docker cp to copy from/to hosts and containers
- use docker exec to run arbitrary shell commands including cp, ssh and many others...

**In docker-compose / kubernetes (or through command line):**

- use volume to share data between containers

  - volume can be local or distant file systems (network disk for example)
- potentially combine that with shell commands for example to perform backups

**Still how you should do it dependy heavily of the use case.**

- If the data you copy is linked to the code and versionned (in the git repo...) then treat as it was code and build the image with it thanks to the Dockerfile. This is for me a best practice.
- If the data is a configuration dependrnt of the environement (like test vs prod, farm 1 vs farm 2), then go for docker config/secret + ENV variables.
- If the data is dynamic and generated at production time (like a DB that is filled with user data as the app is used), use persistant volumes and be sure you understand well the impact of container failure for your data.
- For a database in a test system it can make sense to relauch the DB from a backup dump, a read only persistant volume or much simpler backup the whole container at a known state (with docker commit).

Comment: I guess Ill just create a separate folder and do a different dockerfile.

Comment: I think the best option is to do it at build time, but what Ill need to do is to have multiple Dockerfiles over multiple Folders, and then my docker compose will just build em all.